# Why was this question closed?

Tags: support, closed-questions, moderation, moderators

https://superuser.com/questions/284021/remove-documents-from-main-library-on-kindle

I think this is a legitimate question about a piece of software (the Kindle's OS) which was abruptly closed by a mod with an unhelpful and somewhat disparaging comment.

> Questions on Super User are expected
>   to generally relate to computer
>   software or computer hardware, within
>   the scope defined in the faq.

It doesn't seem like there is a no-Kindle policy here, I see plenty of questions regarding them.

So why was this closed?

Comment: For what it's worth, the comment didn't come from the Moderator. That's the stock comment for any question closed as "off-topic". And I don't see anything "disparaging" there; it's simple statement of fact.

Answer (score 4):

It is off topic as other ereader questions are. Unless they dock with the computer.

> and it is not about...
>
> - videogames or consoles
> - websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress
> - **electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer**
> - a shopping or buying recommendation

Comment: At least be consistent, a quick search for kindle reveals plenty of other questions about kindles not related to computer interfacing...  Are you going to close all of them?

Comment: Yes. Give us mods a minute to close and delete them. @tom

Comment: @Tom unfortunately not all questions are filtered.  We have to realize that SU is moderated by human beings, and although their powers are great, they aren't all inclusive.  There are some questions that slip through the cracks.

Comment: @KronoS: Certainly I can understand that.  It's the manner in which it was done here that I took issue with.

Answer (score 2):

Superuser is about using computers. More precisely, it's an evolving knowledge base about using computers. To build a good knowledge base, you need to set some kind of boundaries on the topics discussed. Ebook readers are sort of like computers, but they're different enough so that it doesn't make sense to deal with them in a computer knowledge base.

Superuser is just one of many [Stack Exchange sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites). There isn't currently one for ebook readers, but over at the Area51 site, people are [working on setting one up](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20794/e-books-and-e-book-readers). Perhaps you should add your voice to the process.