# Time to delete the eBook reader questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, deleted-questions

We have a few questions about eBook readers that I think could be deleted. Most are OT and only invites things like this: [Why was this question closed?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2560/why-was-this-question-closed)

[kindle](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/kindle) <strike>33</strike> 15 questions
[nook](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/nook) <strike>3</strike> 0 questions

Questions that could stay IMO
[How do I get my Windows 7 PC to recognize Kindle 3G (latest gen)?](https://superuser.com/questions/245271/how-do-i-get-my-windows-7-pc-to-recognize-kindle-3g-latest-gen) (about connecting kindle to pc)
[Converting PDF eBooks into a Kindle format](https://superuser.com/questions/225960/converting-pdf-ebooks-into-a-kindle-format) (about converting eBooks)

[Syncing between "Kindle for PC" and "Kindle for iPhone"](https://superuser.com/questions/230170/syncing-between-kindle-for-pc-and-kindle-for-iphone) (about the Kindle for PC app)
[Can I Change the PC File Location for Kindle For PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/191979/can-i-change-the-pc-file-location-for-kindle-for-pc) (about the Kindle for PC app)
[How to preview an HTML file in Kindle for PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/182512/how-to-preview-an-html-file-in-kindle-for-pc)  (about the Kindle for PC app)
[Can I import existing PDF books into Kindle for PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/159893/can-i-import-existing-pdf-books-into-kindle-for-pc)  (about the Kindle for PC app)
[Kindle (client) for Mac – is there text search or highlighting/notes?](https://superuser.com/questions/129802/kindle-client-for-mac-text-search-or-highlighting-notes) (about the Kindle for MAC app)

Should we create the tags [kindle-for-pc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/kindle-for-pc) and [kindle-for-mac](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/kindle-for-mac)?

Comment: Did you want the closed ones deleted? Because indeed a fair bit is about how to interact with the Kindle through the computer, like using Calibre.

Comment: @Ivo - Hmm I have to admit that I didn't bother examining the closed questions. You want me to go through those as well?

Comment: No, I meant did you want me to delete everything Kindle? Because technically they abide by the FAQ as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: @Ivo - And do you think that retagging the questions about `kindle-for-xx` is ok?

Comment: Wouldn't a combination of kindle + windows/osx take care of that? I'm not too familiar with the problems around e-readers.

Comment: @Ivo the problem with just a `kindle` tag is that I think it encourages questions about the device. And the application * kindle-for-xx* is a ebookreader/library app you can use without owning a kindle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The questions have been cleaned up.